# Why do bookmarks stop working after website redirects to new domain?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, dns, bookmarks

After purchasing a new domain (`xyz.com`) and pointing the old domain (`abc.com`) to the new one, I've been receiving notices that bookmarks to the old domain have stopped working; however, visiting the old website directly works fine and redirects to `xyz.com`. I'm unable to reproduce this as I didn't have an old bookmark to `abc.com` but the issue doesn't occur when I create a bookmark. Why wouldn't the old bookmark just redirect to the new domain?

From what I gather, most of the errors are saying the website is unavailable. They have confirmed that the website was not down during the period of time they were trying to use the bookmark. The issue occurred on chrome and potentially IE as well.